# ARIMA(p, d, q) with d > 0 is non-stationary

Tags: time-series

My textbook says:

> An ARIMA(p,d,q) process with $d > 0$ is not stationary and therefore has no stationary
> variance.

Is this just to say that once we have decided to model a process with an ARIMA model with positive difference, we have already admitted that the original process is non-stationary?

Comment: yes. a series that needs to be differencsd in order to become stationary is considered non-stationary.